"General" vs "Galois" Triple Plane
Suggested solution from comments: The curves $R$ and $R_0$ in the definition of "general" triple planes are usually assumed to be different.

I am currently working in the following setting: Let $s(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ define a smooth plane sextic curve $C = V(s)$ over $\mathbb{C}$. I then consider the scheme
\begin{equation}
 X = \text{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[y,x_0,x_1,x_2]/(y^3 - s(x_0,x_1,x_2)) \subseteq \mathbb{P}(2,1,1,1)$
\end{equation}
as well as the morphism
\begin{equation}
 \pi: X \to \mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^2
\end{equation}
given on the level of points by simply forgetting the first coordinate (note that if $(b,a_0,a_1,a_2) \in X$, then necessarily $a_i \neq 0$ for some $i$). This defines a triple plane, i.e. a finite morphism of degree 3 to $\mathbb{P}^2$ with branch locus $C$.
In this paper  the authors define a triple plane to be "general", if the following three properties are satsified:

$\pi$ is unramified over $\mathbb{P}^2\backslash C$.
$\pi^* C = 2R + R_0$ with $R$ irreducible non-singular and $R_0$ reduced.
$f|_R: R \to C$ coincides with the normalization map of $C$.

In my opinion all three of these properties are satisfied by my morphism (in my case the second because $\pi^*C = 3R$ and the third since $C$ is assumed to be smooth itself).
In the same paper it is furthermore stated that if $X$ is smooth (which for my $X$ follows from local inspection), then either $\pi$ is general or $\pi$ is Galois (meaning that the extension of function fields induced by the dominant morphism $\pi$ is Galois). In particular to me this seems to imply exclusivity (either - or, not both).
Now I have a second source from which I seem to be able to deduce a contradiction. In the paper 'Triple covers on smooth algebraic varieties' by (the direct PDF link sadly does not work for me) it is claimed that a triple plane is Galois if and only if it is totally ramified over its branch locus (meaning that preimages of points $P \in C$ have cardinality 1. Again I see no reason why this should not hold for my $X$. Thus my $X$ would be both general and Galois.
My question: Where is my mistake? Is there a property that I wrongly assume to hold?

In the "general case" one usually assumes $R \ne R_0$.

Ah, that clears things up. Thank you :)
